# Folder missing in artifact - GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following steps to copy files to artifact and publish artifact:

```
   - name: copy FA function arm templates
     run: Copy 'Service/Project/Hosts/FA/Infrastructure/' 'upload/functions_arm_templates/FA/Infrastructure'
     shell: powershell
       
   - name: copy FB function arm templates
     run: Copy 'Service/Project/Hosts/FB/Infrastructure/' 'upload/functions_arm_templates/FB/Infrastructure'
     shell: powershell
    
   - name: publish artifact
     uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
     with:
       name: ${{github.run_number}}
       path: upload/**
```

The Build succeeded however after downloading the artifact, I don't see a folder named functions_arm_templates. What am I missing?

Comment: Please add the log of the `upload-artifact` step to your post. Are there any files in these folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only copying the folder without its contents.

Use `copy 'Service/Project/Hosts/FA/Infrastructure/' 'upload/functions_arm_templates/FA/Infrastructure/' -recurse` to copy the folder with its contents.